# Create a unique node representing a complex relationship with other nodes in Neo4j

Tags: merge, neo4j, unique, relationship, cypher

#### Model

I have `Cinema`s, `Film`s and Users and I want to model `View` relationships as first class citizens of the graph, for example: "**Me** went to cinema **#58** to see film **#43483**", in the future I may want add "on **24th May 2013**" or "with **friend1** and **friend2**" to the `View` "relationship", example:

```
CREATE
(u1:User {id:1}),
(u2:User {id:2}),
(f1:Film {id:1}),
(f2:Film {id:2}),
(c1:Cinema {id:1}),
(c2:Cinema {id:2}),
// (v:View), (u1)-[:ATTENDED]->(v),(c1)<-[:AT]-(v),(v)-[:WATCHED]->(f1)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to create a unique `View` (i.e. a person cannot see the same film in the same cinema twice [here's where the extra date relationship will come in]) with a query that if run twice no duplicate `View` node is created.

#### Using CREATE UNIQUE take 1

```
MATCH (c:Cinema {id:1}), (f:Film {id:1}), (u:User {id:1})
CREATE UNIQUE (v:View),
    (u)-[:ATTENDED]->(v),
    (c)<-[:AT]-(v),
    (v)-[:WATCHED]->(f)
return v, u, c, f
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/xcu90c
Creating unique nodes AND relationships seems unsupported.

#### Using CREATE UNIQUE take 2

If I remove the separate node creation, it kind of works, until I don't create a second View:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/x15bk1

#### Using MERGE

```
MATCH (c:Cinema {id:1}), (f:Film {id:1}), (u:User {id:1})
MERGE (u)-[:ATTENDED]->(v:View), (c)<-[:AT]-(v), (v)-[:WATCHED]->(f)
return v, u, c, f
```

Documentation says you can create a path with `MERGE`, but seemingly only straight paths... the above gives a syntax error on comma.

So essentially I don't want a node to be unique (View doesn't have any properties), I want to make the relationships of the node unique. Please suggest a solution.

#### Losing hope

My ideas of possible workarounds are (if all else fails):

- duplicate the cinemaID, filmID and userID on the View node and put a unique constraint on that
- Ignore atomicity and just query, check and create the nodes/relationships in separate queries

So far I'm not impressed with neo4j, so many things don't work which should.

Comment: Based on the answers - leading to the same results - may I have something wrong with the structural design/idea...?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's barfing on the lonely `(v:View)` piece of your pattern in take 1. Try this one:

```
MATCH (c:Cinema { id:58 }),(f:Film { id:43483 }),(u:User { name:"twister" }) 
CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[:ATTENDED]->(v:View),(c)<-[:AT]-(v:View),(v:View)-[:WATCHED]->(f) 
RETURN v, u, c, f
```

Comment: It's the same as take 2, but it fails when I try to create another `View`: `I watched film #1 in cinema #1` and `I watched film #2 in cinema #1`. The result will be **1** `View` with two watched film relationships.

Comment: You're going to need to break it up into multiple merges, I think (in the same command).

Comment: I think that's what @MichaelHunger said in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with multiple MERGE statements, works for me:

```
MATCH (c:Cinema {id:1}), (f:Film {id:1}), (u:User {id:1})
MERGE (u)-[:ATTENDED]->(v:View)
MERGE (c)<-[:AT]-(v)
MERGE (v)-[:WATCHED]->(f)
RETURN v, u, c, f
```

Comment: The syntax works, thanks, but it fails as well when trying to create a second `View` for a different `Cinema`/`Film`/`User`.